# How to change map ID for Google Maps Javascript API within HTML and JS file?

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to give users an option to select what they want displayed on their map, and those choices will determine which Google Maps Styling ID I have associated with the script link that pulls the map. The script link in the html doc looks like this

```
  <script
  async
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=**MYAPIKEY**&map_ids=**MYMAPID**&callback=initMap"
></script>
```

and the function in the js file looks like this

```html
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: lat, lng: lng },
    zoom: 15,
    mapId: "MYMAPID",
  });
}
```

This works all well, if I am only using one mapID. The map ID needs to match in both the JS file and the HTML, so how could I get that to work if say I wanted users to choose options which would lead them to viewing 1 of 5 possible maps?

Answer (score 1):

You can include multiple mapIds in the bootstrap for the API:
(whitespace added for clarity)

```
<script
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
  key=AIzaSyBIwzALxUPNbatRBj3Xi1Uhp0fFzwWNBkE
  &callback=initMap&libraries=
  &v=beta
  &map_ids=dea1fd60813b4e75,6a25ac9af0b8a3a2,2635966e05b3c0d6"
  async
></script>
```

([documentation reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#using_map_ids_in_your_application_code))

The `mapId` doesn't seem to by dynamically changeable with the `.setOptions` method (at least at present), but you can re-construct the map with the new `mapId`.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/jfwmko6a/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8,
    mapId: "dea1fd60813b4e75"
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('grey'), 'click', function() {
    // map.setOptions({mapId:"6a25ac9af0b8a3a2"})
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: {
        lat: -34.397,
        lng: 150.644
      },
      zoom: 8,
      mapId: "6a25ac9af0b8a3a2"
    });
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('classic'), 'click', function() {
    // map.setOptions({mapId:"dea1fd60813b4e75"})
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: {
        lat: -34.397,
        lng: 150.644
      },
      zoom: 8,
      mapId: "dea1fd60813b4e75"
    });
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('light'), 'click', function() {
    // map.setOptions({mapId:"2635966e05b3c0d6"})
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: {
        lat: -34.397,
        lng: 150.644
      },
      zoom: 8,
      mapId: "2635966e05b3c0d6"
    });
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 90%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="grey" type="button" value="grey" />
    <input id="classic" type="button" value="classic" />
    <input id="light" type="button" value="light" />
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=beta&map_ids=dea1fd60813b4e75,6a25ac9af0b8a3a2,2635966e05b3c0d6"
      async
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```